# strtotime 1 month or older issue

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

I'm trying to evaluate and change the color of each row based on the age of the record. For some reason this statement evaluates incorrectly and just paints all rows grey. I have the following values stored in a varchar column
2015-01-12
2015-05-12
2015-05-12

So in theory the first one should be white background and the other two should be grey background. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $mydate = $row['Received_date'];
    if($mydate < strtotime('1 month ago'))
    {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#808080\">";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "
    <td style='font-size:12px;'><center>{$row['ID']}</center></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a date value with a unix time value, and that doesn't work. You're halfway there, though! You're already calling `strtotime()` once; just do it twice and you should hopefully be fine.

```
$mydate = strtotime($row['Received_date']);
```

Comment: I tried 
`$mydate = strtotime($row['Received_Date']);
 if($mydate < strtotime('1 month ago'))
 {
  echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#808080\">";
 }`

but no luck :-/

Comment: I suggest you echo out both of the strtotimed variables and see if there's something wrong there.

Comment: I echo it out and it reads just fine, even tried changing the column format to DATE but the echo just shows "2015-01-12" (inside the quotes) as the value. Wouldn't that mean it could properly compare it again since it's effectively reading if(2015-01-12 < strtotime('1 month ago'))

Comment: No, PHP can't just compare dates like that. For instance, `'2016-01-12' < strtotime('1 month ago')` evaluates to true. The date has to be transformed using `strtotime()` as well. That said, I don't see why the code in your comment doesn't work. It really should, assuming the data in it is correct, which I believe you about when you say it is.